# How to get a value of a nested class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm working on the following problem:

```
    public class Unity
    {
        public Article Article {get;set;}
        public string Text{get;set;}
        public string Description{get;set;}
        public int NumberOfPages{get;set;}
    }
enter code here
    public class Article
    {
        public int Id{get;set;}
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public Category SubCategory {get;set;}
        public Model Model {get;set}

        public string override ToString(){
             return Name;
        }
    }
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id{get;set;}
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public Category CategoryFather { get;set;}
    }
    public class Model{
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public Model ModelFather{get;set;}
    }
```

Imagine i have this domain, i will like to copy the `Name` of the `Article` which i do, but i need out of the Article the `Name` of the `Model` and the `Name` of the `Category`.

I have the next code to copy:

```
public static List<DataPropertyReport> GetPrimitiveProperties<T>(T entity)
        {
            var properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();

            List<DataPropertyReport> info = new List<DataPropertyReport>();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                Object value = property.GetValue(entity, null);

                    var name = property.Name;
                    info.Add(new DataPropertyReport(name, value!=null?value.ToString():"", 1));    
            }

            return info;
        }
```

Comment: Recursively..!!

Comment: Can you elavorate more your answer? because before you answer i was traying to do it recursively

Comment: What is your expect output and what is the structure of `DataPropertyReport`?

Comment: @DanielAcevedo - Posted a recursive answer which should fetch the nested class properties values too.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by vendettamit, you can achieve using recursion. The below code achieve **basic implementation for primitives** data type and class. You have to handle various code flow based on your object structure.

```
    public static List<DataPropertyReport> GetPrimitiveProperties<T>(T entity, string heirarchyName = null)
    {
        List<DataPropertyReport> info = new List<DataPropertyReport>();
        if (entity != null)
        {
            var properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                Object value = property.GetValue(entity, null);

                var name = property.Name;
                var relatedHeirarchyName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(heirarchyName) ? name : string.Concat(heirarchyName, ".", name);
                if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string) && property.PropertyType.IsClass)
                {
                    var reports = GetPrimitiveProperties(value, relatedHeirarchyName);
                    info.AddRange(reports);
                }
                else
                {
                    info.Add(new DataPropertyReport(relatedHeirarchyName, value != null ? value.ToString() : "", 1));
                }
            }
        }

        return info;
    }
```

For below object

```
        Unity unity = new Unity()
        {
            NumberOfPages = 1,
            Description = "Test Des",
            Text = "Test Text",
            Article = new Article()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "test Article",
                Model = new Model()
                {
                    Name = "Test Model",
                    Id = 2,
                    ModelFather = new Model()
                    {
                        Id = 3,
                        Name = "Test Father Model"
                    }
                },
                SubCategory = new Category()
                {
                    Name = "Test Category",
                    Id = 4,
                    CategoryFather = new Category()
                    {
                        Id = 5,
                         Name = "Test Category Fathere"
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

The output is

> Name : Article.Id   Value : 1
>
> Name : Article.Name   Value : test Article
>
> Name : Article.SubCategory.Id   Value : 4
>
> Name : Article.SubCategory.Name   Value : Test Category
>
> Name : Article.SubCategory.CategoryFather.Id   Value : 5
>
> Name : Article.SubCategory.CategoryFather.Name   Value : Test Category Fathere
>
> Name : Article.Model.Id   Value : 2
>
> Name : Article.Model.Name   Value : Test Model
>
> Name : Article.Model.ModelFather.Id   Value : 3
>
> Name : Article.Model.ModelFather.Name   Value : Test Father Model
>
> Name : Text   Value : Test Text
>
> Name : Description   Value : Test Des
>
> Name : NumberOfPages   Value : 1

Based on below ToString implementation of `DataPropertyReport`

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name : {this.Name}   Value : {this.Value}";
    }
```

Comment: Lets hope he never tries to step over DateTime or Decimal.... otherwise, thumbs up.

Comment: @MortenBork - Thanks. As mentioned in my answer that the answered code has basic implementation.SO has to handle other scenarios like DateTime, double (as mentioned by you), Nullable, Generic e.t.c.